# Is there a chess GUI that gives an evaluation of each move?

Tags: engines

I'm looking for a chess GUI that shows the evaluation of each possible move rather than the top move.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19264/how-much-does-high-multipv-setting-harm-engine-strength I quite disagree with the statement that engines go completely stupid showing all the lines from the accepted answer, if you like, you can check answers in my new question.

Comment: Ok my mistake, it really slows down calculations heavily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most GUIs you can set up top x moves. The reason why there is no program showing all moves, is that it would be terribly slow if you would make it show a lot of moves because of the engine.

All engines use some version of Alpha-Beta Search, without getting in the details of it, the point is, if a move is outside the interval of Alpha-Beta it is not examined further, so you can't really decide if it's right out of the window, or way off. If the engine wouldn't use this filtering, than it would need to check all branches, making it way too slow.

tl;dr

I don't think there is a GUI like that, if there is than the results it shows are completely bad, they would have the strength of a chess program from the 50s.

Comment: However, OP could be thinking of a GUI that does use Alpha-Beta to narrow the tree, but which calculates for each of the x moves which are *immediately* possible by the side to play. Say it's White's turn, and there are 50 possible moves. It would take around 50 times as long, so an hour of calculation instead of a minute, but not as weak as a 50s program. I still agree that it is unlikely that anyone would consider such a functionality to be valuable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! **Lucas chess** gives the evaluation for all the moves you play. Download latest version.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to provide a link, please?